# SQL Query using Joins: ORA-00979 error

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to execute one sql query using joins, but I'm getting the below error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

The query is to count the number of normalized_event_ids along with the error message and error_ids using two tables.:

```
select count(nee.normalised_event_id),
       em.error_message,
       em.error_message_id 
from normalised_event_error nee, error_message em 
where nee.charge_start_date >= to_date('01-07-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') 
and nee.error_message_id = em.error_message_id 
group by em.error_message;
```

Comment: You didn't name all the SELECT fields into the GROUP BY statement.. you are missing error_message_id in the GROUP BY...

Comment: First of all get rid of these old styled joins. Use the explicit word join and put `em.error_message_id ` in group by clause

Comment: The fact that your query includes a join doesn't change anything. In Oracle the GROUP BY clause must include all the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - some people are obsessed with the use of ANSI 92 syntax. But the older style syntax is **completely irrelevant** to this question. So why lead with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    em.error_message,
    em.error_message_id, 
    count(nee.normalised_event_id) 
from normalised_event_error nee, 
     error_message em 
where nee.charge_start_date >= to_date('01-07-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') 
and nee.error_message_id = em.error_message_id 
group by em.error_message, em.error_message_id;
```

Comment: Can you explain for the OP, why he/she must use this query?

Answer (score 3):

```
  SELECT COUNT (nee.normalised_event_id), em.error_message, em.error_message_id
    FROM normalised_event_error nee
         INNER JOIN error_message em
            ON nee.error_message_id = em.error_message_id
   WHERE nee.charge_start_date >= TO_DATE ('01-07-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
GROUP BY em.error_message, em.error_message_id;
```

The select columns and group by columns must be same for grouping.

Comment: Don't give a anwser that is still using the old JOIN syntax.. use the JOIN keyword..

Answer (score 2):

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8af3/5/0)

You need to add error_message_id column to the group by clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(nee.normalised_event_id) as messages,
       em.error_message,
       em.error_message_id 
FROM normalised_event_error nee
    JOIN error_message em ON em.error_message_id = nee.error_message_id
WHERE nee.charge_start_date >= to_date('01-07-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') 
GROUP BY em.error_message, em.error_message_id;
```